# How can I implement adobe stratus client in C#?

Tags: c#, flash, actionscript-3, p2p

In [actionscript3 I am able to create a p2p network](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/stratus/) and send arbitary text data around. While this works fine in a [network of flash clients](https://admin.na3.acrobat.com/_a204547676/p85387367/) I would like to connect a non flash client **written instead in c#** to **the same p2p network**.

Is anybody working on such a thing already? Are there any articles on how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think the most simple thing really is to create a C# client that'll embed an SWF for communication purpose ... communication between C# and SWF can be done easily through local connections ...

otherwise, you will be having a hard time ... i summarized how flash p2p works in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110880/does-flash10-p2p-really-work/1111129#1111129) ... there is an awful lot of net-code you will be having to write (starting with the whole protocols that stratus alone uses, and then reimplementing the whole p2p protocol based on UDP, which secures data much like TCP does, and should not be a twoliner) ... i'm not saying it is not feasible ... but it seems unneccessarily uncomplicated ...

greetz

back2dos

Comment: that would be one way to go, but I'd have an open source stratus client and maybe in the future the server also. :) might be I am asking for too much